# How can I adjust the legend box?

Tags: r, plot

This is my code:

```
score <- tapply(exams$writing.score 
                   , list(exams$gender,
                          exams$race.ethnicity
                          )
                   , mean)

plot1 <- barplot(score
                 , beside = TRUE
                 , main = "Comparison of Writing Score"
                 , col = c("red", "lightyellow")
                 , xlab = "Race Ethnicity Group"
                 , ylab = "Average Writing Score"
                 , legend.text = c("Female", "Male")
                 , args.legend = list(x = "topright")
)
```

[image]

As I want to make the box: Female and Male smaller so it does not hide the bar behind. How can I make the legend box smaller? I tried to move it to the top right of the chart, but I do not think it moves.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the argument `cex`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
data <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), ncol = 5)

colnames(data) <- paste0("V", 1:5)
rownames(data) <- c('A','B')

# Normal
barplot(data, col = 1:nrow(data))
legend("topright", legend = rownames(data), pch = 15, col = 1:nrow(data))
```

[image]

```r
# With cex
barplot(data, col = 1:nrow(data))
legend("topright", legend = rownames(data), pch = 15, col = 1:nrow(data), cex = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Another option (in addition to using `cex` as @Quinten shows) is to also change the `inset` to move the legend outside of the plot boundary, as well as using `par` to specify the parameters for margins, etc.

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 8),
    xpd = TRUE)

# Normal
barplot(df, col = 1:nrow(df))
legend(
  "topright",
  inset = c(-0.1, 0),
  # Create legend outside of plot
  legend = rownames(df),
  pch = 15,
  col = 1:nrow(df),
  cex = 0.8
)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), dim = c(2L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("Female", "Male"), c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't move because you already are at the very top. To move the top upwards and let the legend follow, expand `ylim`.

Also try if you like setting the legend `horiz`ontal and remove the `bty` (boxtype). Don't choose the `cex` too small.

```
barplot(score
        , beside=TRUE
        , main="Comparison of Writing Score"
        , col=c("red", "lightyellow")
        , xlab="Race Ethnicity Group"
        , ylab="Average Writing Score"
        , legend.text=c("Female", "Male")
        , args.legend=list(x="topright", cex=.9, horiz=TRUE, bty='n')
        , ylim=c(0, max(score)*1.2)
)
```

### [image]

*Data:*

```
score <- structure(c(96.8, 95.2, 100, 100, 89.7, 89.2, 81.4, 81, 85.1, 
82), dim = c(2L, 5L), dimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E")))
```